# Printing all even and odd numbers with threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

The original question is on [careercup.](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5652784707796992)

> Write a multi threaded C code with one thread printing all even numbers and the other all odd numbers. The output should always be in sequence
>   ie. 0,1,2,3,4....etc

Now I want to use  `C#` for it.

```
class Program
{
    static Object obj = new Object();
    static Thread t1;
    static Thread t2;
    static LinkedList<int> a = new LinkedList<int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a.AddLast(i);
        }

        t1 = new Thread(PrintOdd);
        t2 = new Thread(PrintEven);
        t1.Name = "Odd";
        t2.Name = "Even";
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void PrintOdd()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (a.Count == 0)
                break;
            lock (obj)
            {
                int x = a.First();
                if (x % 2 != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + x);
                    a.RemoveFirst();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void PrintEven()
    {
        while (true)
        { 
            lock (obj)
            {
                if (a.Count == 0)
                    break;
                int x = a.First();
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + x);
                    a.RemoveFirst();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any improvements?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks very good to me, but I am not very advanced at C# myself.  I can give you some tips, though.

First, you should not use ambiguous names like `t1` and `t2`.  You should use more descriptive names like `EvenThread` and `OddThread` instead.

Second, you can shorten this:

```
while (true)
{
  if (a.Count == 0)
    break;
```

Into this:

```
while (Numbers.Count > 0)  // For PrintOdd()
```

And this:

```
while (Numbers.Count > 1)  // For PrintEven()
```

Also, you could look into other forms of mutual exclusion techniques, such as semaphores and mutexes, instead of just using an `Object`.

This is an implementation with a `SemaphoreSlim` (only code shown is changed):

```
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static SemaphoreSlim ThreadLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
    static Thread Odd;
    static Thread Even;
    static LinkedList<int> Numbers = new LinkedList<int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Numbers.AddLast(i);
        }

        Odd = new Thread(PrintOdd);
        Even = new Thread(PrintEven);
        Odd.Name = "Odd";
        Even.Name = "Even";
        Odd.Start();
        Even.Start();
        Odd.Join();
        Even.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void PrintOdd()
    {
        while (Numbers.Count > 0)
        {
            ThreadLock.Wait();

            int x = Numbers.First();
            if (x % 2 != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + x);
                Numbers.RemoveFirst();
            }

            ThreadLock.Release();
        }
    }

    private static void PrintEven()
    {
        while (Numbers.Count > 1)
        {
            ThreadLock.Wait();

            int x = Numbers.First();
            if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + x);
                Numbers.RemoveFirst();
            }

            ThreadLock.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using same logic in two methods, you can write just one method for both of the threads.

Please see below:

```
    private static LinkedList<int> _numbers;
    private static readonly object _numLock = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _numbers = new LinkedList<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            _numbers.AddLast(i);
        }

        var evenThread = new Thread(x => PrintNumbers(true));
        var oddThread = new Thread(x => PrintNumbers(false));

        evenThread.Name = "Even";
        oddThread.Name = "Odd";

        evenThread.Start();
        oddThread.Start();

        evenThread.Join();
        oddThread.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void PrintNumbers(bool isEven)
    {
        bool condition = true;
        while (condition)
        {
            lock (_numLock)
            {
                var first = _numbers.First;
                if (isEven && first.Value % 2 == 0)
                {
                    WriteAndRemove(first);
                }
                else if (!isEven && first.Value % 2 == 1)
                {
                    WriteAndRemove(first);
                }
                condition = isEven ? _numbers.Count > 1 : _numbers.Count > 0;
            }

        }
    }

    private static void WriteAndRemove(LinkedListNode<int> first)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(Thread.CurrentThread.Name," " ,first.Value));
        _numbers.RemoveFirst();
    }
```

Comment: You don't need an `else if` with the same contents, if you change the condition to `(first.Value % 2 == (isEven ? 1 : 0))`

Answer (score -3):

Instead of checking the modulo via `if (x % 2 == 0)` and  `if (x % 2 != 0)` you could simply use `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + (2*x));` and `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + (2*x+1));` to display even an odd numbers respectively. As a mathematician this seems more reasonable to me.

Comment: If the collection starts at `1` this won't work. For such an interview question one should always assume that the input for the method to be written can change ( like in the real job )

Comment: Yeah but since _all_ even and odd numbers should be printed this would produce the desired result.

Comment: Won't work. Because you have 2 threads. It prints with the code in the question, using your idea, `Odd 1` `Odd 3` `Odd 5` ... `Odd 19`. No `Even` there ;-(

Comment: This does seem a little strange because 2*x is _always_ even. So without the actual code there is nothing more I can do.

Comment: Sure it is even, but as the thread `t1` is started first and also the linked list isn't big, that thread will call `int x = a.First();` Print `2*x +1` followed by `a.RemoveFirst();` and this inside a loop. There is no chance for `t2` to get any item of the list because `t1` is to fast.

Comment: But why did the original code work? I don't get how my suggestion should modify the former order of execution.

Comment: The original code works, because the loops will iterate until `a.Count == 0` and they only print and remove the entry from the list if the modulo condition is true.

Answer (score -3):

Above application is not a really good solution.

There are the following problems in it:

- Why do you want to thread to wait? It does not finds even or odd number since it is checking on first value only.
- If your list size is odd number like 11 or 13

Please do proper unit test to ensure it also for even list size.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review AMIT - I have reviewed your answer, and while I believe it is an answer, what it's saying is wrong. The code does not have the problems your answer says it does.